# How to avoid "Complete action with" popup with OAuth callbacks from Google?

Tags: android, android-intent, oauth-2.0, openid

I am playing around with OpenID Connect and OAuth and I want to support multiple OpenID providers (so not only the ones known by the AccountManager). However, I ran into this issue.

When authenticating against Google as an Installed Application, you pass a callback address, which is pre-defined (by Google) to `http://localhost`. So, I launch the OAuth flow by redirecting to Google's end-point like this:

```
String url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&state=%2F&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9999&response_type=code&client_id=000000000000000.apps.googleusercontent.com";
Intent i = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData (Uri.parse (url));
startActivity (i);
```

Note that I pass the redirect_uri as required (port 9999, which is allowed). I have registered my application to respond to this type of address being loaded as follows:

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="localhost" android:port="9999" />
```

However, this causes the system to show the "Complete action with" dialog:

[image]

So, since there is nothing listening on port 9999 of the phone, if the user chooses the Browser, an error page will be shown by the Browser and the whole authentication flow will be broken.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Did you consider using the AccountManager? You wouldn't have to worry about that stuff...

Comment: @TomTasche, I would like to also allow login with other OpenID Connect providers (not only the ones that are known to Android at the time). I mention it in the beginning of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the redirect url have a different scheme, e.g. `app://localhost`. All browsers register as handlers for `http` and `https`, so that part of the problem is not solvable. If, however, the redirect URL can have a non-standard scheme, your problem becomes easy to solve. Invent your own scheme and use that (lots of apps do that, Facebook have `fb://` links for example).

Comment: Yes, I know that works, but I was looking for a generalized solution. Google doesn't allow custom schemes with OAuth authentication when the app is registered as such (an app). However, if no other solution is presented, I guess I'll use this approach and hange Google's case separately.

Answer (score 0):

Perform authentication in a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) shown directly in your app.

Here is short example how you make it load OAuth page, and how you detect when browser tries to redirect to your oauth callback. At this point, just grab token and close login activity or dialog.

This way you don't need to register your app to handle scheme or port, since external web browser is not used.

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.wv);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
   final String cb = "http://your_oauth_callback_uri";
   @Override
   public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
   if(url.startsWith(cb)) {
      view.stopLoading();
      Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
      String token = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");
      // TODO do whatever you need with token
   }
});
webView.loadUrl(uri);
```

You have to make the rest - activity, layout, etc.

Note: this code is taken from my OAuth 1 app, but should work also with your case, except that returned oauth_token param may have different name.

Comment: the issue with using a WebView is the fact that the user doesn't see the chrome of the browser, the address bar and (possibly) the SSL certificate information. On top of that, if the user was logged in with Google, Facebook, etc., the logged-in state will not be available in my WebView, since that is maintained by the browser's cookies. So, my app would look like a phishing scheme - trying to get the user to type in his/her credentials when they had already done that (from the perspective of the user, they don't know the technical reasons behind the need to enter credentials again...).

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way around this; Android does not allow one activity to make itself preferred over another for handling a given intent, it's always the user's choice. You are expected to use the AccountManager or a WebView for this kind of login flow, not the browser (see [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps)). Google is unlikely to be the only OpenID provider which disallows using an arbitrary URL scheme as the callback; I can imagine some vague security reasons for this.

Android users in general are going to expect you to use AccountManager; that's a familiar UI that many trusted apps use. Even if you get sending them to a browser to work, I suspect that a lot of less technical users will find that surprising and be concerned about it *anyway*, even though they have the theoretical comfort of the browser chrome/etc as you mention.

If you really want it to work using the browser, you will have to actually start a small HTTP server on a random port number and use that port as the callback (the way installed-app OpenID is meant to work); not impossible, but not trivial either.